# ¿Por qué recibo tantos datos basura?

Tags: arduino, mqtt

tengo un programa simple que me imprime desde un nodemcu dos string que recibe consecutivamente, es decir, primero envio un string y luego el otro. En este me suceden muchos problemas, el primero es que al recibir cualquiera de los dos strings estos vienen con basura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y luego al enviar el segundo mensaje en una variable totalmente distinta me llega la información combinada del primer envio con el del segundo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

Caracteres extraños puedeb deverse a diversos factores:

1. Baudrate incorrecto: Si empleas dos baudrate distintos para leer y escribir se van a publicar caracteres extraños pues el receptor no entiende lo que está recibiendo. Viendo los mensajes, no tiene pinta de ser esto pues hay caracteres que re los está reconociendo.
2. Como estas enviando strings, depende de la incialización esos strings pueden no estar vacíos (ej: en el primer caso, si has enviado la palabra arriba, los siguientes caracteres pueden deverse a que el resto del string estaba inicializado con cosas aleatorias). Esto es lo que veo más probable, suponiendo que en el segundo mensaje estés mandando un 87, al no estar vaciando el string de nuevo se te están manteniendo los caracteres del comienzo.

Sin ver el código no se puede decir mucho más, pero yo diría que es la segunda cuestión. Hay más opciones de recibir caracteres incorrectos, pero por el momento las descarto. Si adjuntas el código quizás te podamo echar una mano.
Para la solución de la cuestión 2, hay que emplear la función memset para inicializar el string como vacío:

```
memset(&string,0,sizeof(string));
```

Un saludo!